# From method in lumen 8 mailable class not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, lumen, lumen-8

I am using mailable to send emails from my application. The mail "from" can be different that is why I cannot use variables from the env or mail config class. So I decided to use mailable. It sends emails with the dynamic name "mailFromName" but does not use the "mailFrom" parameter while sending an email. Neither this work with dynamic parameters nor with the hardcoded addresses rather it sends email using parameters from env. Can anybody guide me on this error?

```
<?php
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ReportGenerated extends Mailable
{
  use Queueable, SerializesModels;

  public $data;
  public $otherInformation;
  /**
  * Create a new message instance.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function __construct($data,$otherInformation)
  {
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->otherInformation=$otherInformation;
  }

   /**
    * Build the message.
    *
    * @return $this
    */
  public function build()
  {
    $data = $this->data;
    $otherInformation = $this->otherInformation;             
    $mailFrom = $otherInformation["mailFrom"];
    $mailFromName = $otherInformation["mailFromName"];
    return $this->from($mailFrom,$mailFromName)->subject("Your report is ready")->view('emailReport',compact("data","otherInformation"));
}
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem, I'm having the same issue...

Comment: @MarinarioAgalliu I couldn't find its solution unfortunately. If you have found please share with us.

Comment: have a look at: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/configuring-the-sender-using-the-from-method-will-not-send-the-email-only-to-gmail-addreses?page=1